# If a method is called from within a synchronized method, is the inner method's access to shared mutable data thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a top-level service which has a method A, which accesses shared data and is declared synchronized. Method A in turn calls method B of an internal class, which accesses some shared data of its own.

If I can guarantee that B is only called from the API of the top level service and is not publicly exposed, do I still need to declare B as synchronized? Or is the synchronized declaration of A enough to ensure that B is thread-safe too?

Is there a performance penalty in declaring B synchronized as well?

Comment: Can you please give some code to understand more.If your data is shared then it will access by multiple thread.Then visibility required.

Answer (score 0):

The key really is that B is not called from somewhere else. As long as this is ensured, you are fine.

There is a small performance penalty if you make B synchronized as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be fine.

```
syncronized(object) {
    do thing one;
    do thing two;
}
```

is the same as

```
syncronized(object) {
    doSomething();
}

void doSomething() {
    do thing one;
    do thing two;
}
```

as long as a lock is held on the **object**, everything that goes inside the syncronized block will be an atomic operation